# AlarmManager не из MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-alarm-manager, pendingintent

При создании `AlarmManager` внутри `MainActivity` все нормально работает. В заданное время запускается другая активити:

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AlarmActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(MainActivity.this, iterator, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, key, pendingIntent);
```

Но если сделать то же самое не из `MainActivity`, а, например из того же класса `AlarmActivity`, то по достижении заданного времени ничего не происходит.

Intent intent = new Intent(***this***, AlarmActivity.class);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(***this***, ...);

Проблема скорее всего в `context`, но вот какой он должен быть, если интент создается не из `MainActivity`? Пробовал и через this и через `AlarmActivity.this`, и через `getApplicationContext()`

**UPDATE**

На alarmActivity есть кнопка "Отложить", при нажатии на которую, alarm обновляется и activity закрывается

```
public void hold(View view)
{
    long hold = 0;
    long currentTime = new Date().getTime();

    if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
        //hold = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        hold = 5000; //for test
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1)
        hold = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2)
        hold = 15 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3)
        hold = 30 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4)
        hold = 60 * 60 * 1000;

    currentTime += hold;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, AlarmActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currentTime, pendingIntent);

    this.finish();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответили на [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168935/alarmmanager-not-from-mainactivity), все получилось, работает как надо.

В общем, нужно было создать класс и унаследовать его от BroadcastReceiver, заимплементить метод onReceive:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmActivity.class);

        int requestCode = intent.getExtras().getInt("intRequest");
        String alarmContent = intent.getExtras().getString("keyContent");

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("intRequest", requestCode);
        bundle.putString("keyContent", alarmContent);
        activityIntent.putExtras(bundle);

        activityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(activityIntent);
    }
}
```

Далее нужно в манифесте добавить

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" > </receiver>
```

Ну а потом, в моем методе класса AlarmActivity уже можно создавать AlarmManager

```
public void hold(View view)
{
    long hold = 0;
    long currentTime = new Date().getTime(); //System.currentTimeMillis()

    if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 0)
        //hold = 5 * 60 * 1000;
        hold = 5000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 1)
        hold = 10 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 2)
        hold = 15 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 3)
        hold = 30 * 60 * 1000;
    else if (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition() == 4)
        hold = 60 * 60 * 1000;

    currentTime += hold;

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) AlarmActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmActivity.this, AlarmReceiver.class);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt("intRequest", requestCode);
    bundle.putString("keyContent", String.valueOf(textViewAlarmContent.getText()));
    intent.putExtras(bundle);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, requestCode, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, currentTime, pendingIntent);

    this.finish();
}
```